# hive alter table partition concatenate doesn't work

Tags: hive

I want to concatenate multiple files into 1 file in a partition.

I do:

```
alter table default.clickstream_v3 partition (export_date = '2023-01-01', day = '2022-12-31') concatenate;
```

but it doesn't work, because I then check it and there is no change, I still have multiple files:

```
[root@node-master2MgdsdHkR ~]# hdfs dfs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/clickstream_v3/export_date=2023-01-01/day=2022-12-31
Found 4 items
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root hive   67137779 2023-07-19 12:55 /user/hive/warehouse/clickstream_v3/export_date=2023-01-01/day=2022-12-31/000000_0
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root hive   44193051 2023-07-19 12:55 /user/hive/warehouse/clickstream_v3/export_date=2023-01-01/day=2022-12-31/000001_0
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root hive   41652499 2023-07-19 12:55 /user/hive/warehouse/clickstream_v3/export_date=2023-01-01/day=2022-12-31/000002_0
-rw-rw-rw-   3 root hive   36238581 2023-07-19 12:55 /user/hive/warehouse/clickstream_v3/export_date=2023-01-01/day=2022-12-31/000003_0
```

My table is stored in orc with zlib compression.

How do I get this to work?

So far I tried different execution engines (mr, tez) to no avail.

After I execute the `alter table` command I see that the timestamp of files in hdfs changes, so, the command did execute and write something. I feel like there's some setting missing that specifies some threshold for concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/How-to-compact-ORC-files-on-Hive/ta-p/248468 I found this awesome article on cloudera, it recommends applying these settings before doing ‘alter table partition concatenate’:

```
SET hive.merge.tezfiles=true; 
SET hive.execution.engine=tez;
SET hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.size.per.task=256000000;
SET hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=256000000;
SET hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
SET hive.merge.orcfile.stripe.level=true;
SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize=256000000;
SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=256000000;
SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.node=256000000;
SET mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize.per.rack=256000000;
```

Also, I noticed, that you can, for example, change 256... values to 512, and it will create bigger files.

Experiment with it and try it out!